# Could not find 'ruby2_keywords' (>= 0.0.4) among 141 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) in m1 while running fastlane sigh

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, apple-m1, fastlane

While running the fastlane sigh I got the below error "Could not find 'ruby2_keywords' (>= 0.0.4) among 141 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0:/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    16: from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
    15: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
    14: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `synchronize'
    13: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
     5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
     2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1449:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'ruby2_keywords' (>= 0.0.4) among 141 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0:/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

which fastlane

```
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/fastlane
```

% gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.3.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.1.0 (2021-12-25 patchlevel 0) [arm64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.gem/ruby/3.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - arm64-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0
     - /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin
     - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0@global/bin
     - /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/bin
     - /Users/name/.fastlane/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /Users/name/.rvm/bin
```

which ruby

```
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby
```

% rvm list

```
=* ruby-3.1.0 [ arm64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

which fastlane

```
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/fastlane
```

fastlane --v

```
fastlane installation at path:
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/fastlane-2.200.0/bin/fastlane
-----------------------------
[✔]  
fastlane 2.200.0
```

While running the above it shows the path as /usr/local/bin/fastlane. If I remove this fastlane, it shows there is no fastlane in your machine.